# Is there a way to upload a quantity price schedule (csv, perhaps) in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I am working in netsuite, and I am wondering if there is a way to upload a Quantity Price Schedule (we have a lot). I'll take any method - suiteScript, suiteTalk, UI.

I am looking into doing it through suiteTalk but it does not appear that Quantity Price Schedules are an actual object, but appears to only be a field on other records. Is that true?

you can probably tell - I am new to netsuite. Any answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few articles in the NetSuite help that explains Quantity Pricing Schedules. These may help you:

https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/section_N2183677.html?NS_VER=2015.1.0

https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/section_N380976.html?NS_VER=2015.1.0

Comment: Thanks for the response. More what I am looking for is how to upload an actual template, as they call it in the articles. These articles describe an ITEM import that uses quantity pricing, not the quantity schedules themselves.